# is there an example of a canvasJS graph where each point on a graph has a tick and label on the X axis?

Tags: javascript, graph, canvasjs

I cannot seem to find an example where every single point in a set of data had its own tick and label on a graph. when I load in my data, CanvasJS gives me intervals as my x axis. the actual points are placed inbetween these intervals. If i add more data, the intervals dont change. I am looking for an example of how to make it so each point is represented.

I would also like the xaxis to look as identical to this formatting as possible
[image]

I have read some documentation [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/formatting-numbers/) but I am struggling to make it work for me. My X axis values look like this: 119604384477647324 but are in Miliseconds.

any help would be appreciated. I have a presentation soon and I am hard stuck. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas.js](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/) offers a wide range of charts that can be used with a variety of ways to customize them. One key thing to keep in mind is to ensure that your data array `dataPoint` is in the correct format and contains all corresponding elements.

I believe what you are trying to do can be done through utilizing `valueFormatString` variable, kindly find below a similar example that creates an area chart when working with timestamp data (stored as Unix Timestamp in milliseconds).

```js
                            function timeConverter(timestamp) {
                              const date = new Date(timestamp);
                              const year = date.getFullYear();
                              const month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                              const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                              const hours = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
                              const minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
                              const seconds = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
                              return `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
                            }

                                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("download_overtime_day", {
                                    animationEnabled: true, 
                                    toolTip:{   
                                            contentFormatter: function (e) {
                                            var content = timeConverter(e.entries[0].dataPoint.x) + " : " + e.entries[0].dataPoint.y + " Template Downloaded";
                                            return content;
                                        }      
                                    }, 
                                    zoomEnabled: true, 
                                    title:{
                                        text: "Daily View (Past 24 Hours)"
                                    },
                                    theme: "light2",
                                    exportFileName: "Daily View (Past 24 Hours) - 2023-04-26 01:52:45",
                                    exportEnabled: true,
                                    backgroundColor: "",
                                    axisX: {
                                        title: "Hour of The Day",
                                        valueFormatString: "HH:mm:ss",
                                        labelAngle: -30
                                    },
                                    axisY: {
                                        title: "Downloads",
                                        valueFormatString: "#0",
                                        suffix: " Tem..",
                                        maximum: 6
                                    },
                                    data: [{
                                        type: "area",
                                        xValueType: "dateTime",
                                        dataPoints: [{"x":1682460000000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682463600000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682467200000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682470800000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682474400000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682478000000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682481600000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682485200000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682488800000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682492400000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682496000000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682499600000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682502686000,"y":1,"markerSize":13,"indexLabel":"1","indexLabelFontSize":13},{"x":1682503200000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682506800000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682510400000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682514000000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682517086000,"y":1,"markerSize":13,"indexLabel":"1","indexLabelFontSize":13},{"x":1682517600000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682521200000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682524800000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682528400000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682532000000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682535600000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682539200000,"y":0,"markerSize":0},{"x":1682542800000,"y":0,"markerSize":0}]
                                    }]
                                });

                                chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="download_overtime_day" style="height:400px;width:100%"></div>
```

Also, many examples can be found on how to handle time series data in many ways such as storing the data in `Date` format as well (not limited to Unix Timestamp). Kindly find [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/).

Hope it helped :)!